# Cheese cookie doughs and proportions

Tags: dough, cheese, cookies, ratio, ingredients

Cheese cookie recipes I looked at use varying ingredients and ratios. Having never baked before, I'd like to know what those do to the result and what the gamut of workable variation in proportions is.

Some recipes include wet ingredients like vegetable pieces. I don't plan on that currently.

The first matter is how much cheese I can load the cookies with! [Many recipes](https://southernbite.com/easy-cheese-straw-cookies-cheese-happies/) use grated cheese, flour, and butter in about equal amounts. Then there's the kind that's baked dollops of pure cheese (plus spices or seeds). (What are those called in English?) Does any point along that scale work out with the same dough?

Next, some doughs have eggs and some don't. I presume eggs make the cookie moister and softer. But [one recipe](https://www.chefkoch.de/rezepte/3431501511199218/Kaesetaler-mit-Garnelen-und-Tomaten.html) has 2 eggs with just cheese and baking powder. What is its function -- is the cheese not sticky enough on its own to hold gas bubbles?

[Another variant](https://www.chefkoch.de/rezepte/1809921293034109/Schinken-Kaese-Taler.html) has equal amounts flour, grated cheese, diced bacon, and quark cheese with some oil, plus eggs and baking powder. Does the quark constitute a butter substitute? Has the choice anything to do with holding the additional mass of bacon, or is it to offset its fattiness?

What are the characters of these different doughs, how do they result from the ingredients? How much cheese can I put in?

Comment: The three examples are _very_ different from each other. (And the term “cookie” can probably be applied only in the very widest sense for some.) Your question is quite interesting, but very, very broad.

Comment: @Stephie, I don't know enough to narrow it. Might post about each separately I guess. For the moment let's say the main q is what the characters are; modification and in parricular cheese amount could wait til I can decide on one style.